# Can't log in to Github for Mac client after changing my computer's name

Tags: macos, git, github, ssh, github-for-mac

I changed my computer's name, and now I cannot log into the Github for Mac client.  When I try to log in through the "preferences" section in Github for Mac, I get a "Login or password is incorrect" message.  I am certain that they are in fact, correct.

I figured this had something to do with my SSH key being tied to my computer name, so I generated a new SSH key.

After changing my SSH key, and adding it through github.com, I ran:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get the success message:

```
Hi alexweissman! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I also did

```
git config --global user.email <my-email-address>
```

Which seemed to work without any complaint.

Strangely, when I attempt to sync a commit, and it prompts me for my username and password, it accepts it without any complaint.  I suspect that Github for Mac has cached my old SSH key somewhere and is somehow trying to use that in conjunction with the "remember me" feature.

I am running OSX 10.8.5.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Go to https://github.com/settings/applications and revoke the access to GitHub For Mac. Then try the login

Comment: I have the same issue and this, unfortunately didn't work for me.